# Error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"num\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Return\"

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to include pagination. I was able to implement this on other screens that I have which deal with my orders, but I can't get it to work on my `ReturnListScreen.js`. Currently, I'm getting an error stating `Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"num\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Return\`. This error has to do with my `returnPagesActions` and `returnPagesReducer`, but I'm unsure of why I keep getting this error as I haven't done anything different in my set up of these. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions on why this might be happening and how to fix this. Thank you!

Frontend

ReturnListScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {listReturns returnPagesActions } from '../actions/returnActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { RETURN_DELETE_RESET } from '../constants/returnConstants';
import Pagination from '../components/Pagination';

export default function ReturnListScreen(props) {
  const pageNumber = props.match.params.pageNumber || 1;
  const [page, setPage] = useState(pageNumber);
  const returnList = useSelector((state) => state.returnList);
  const { loading, error, returns } = returnList;
  const returnPages = useSelector((state) => state.returnPages);
  const { totalPages } = returnPages;
  const returnDelete = useSelector((state) => state.returnDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = returnDelete;

const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(listReturns(page));
    dispatch(returnPagesActions());
  },[dispatch, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: RETURN_DELETE_RESET });
  }, [dispatch, successDelete, userInfo._id]);



  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="name_id">Returns</h1>
      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorDelete && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorDelete}</MessageBox>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <div>
           <Pagination page={page} totalPages={totalPages} changePage={setPage}/>
        <table className="table">
         ...
          
        </table>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

returnActions.js

```
export const returnPagesActions = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: RETURN_PAGE_REQUEST });
    const {
        userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/returns/num`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
           
        });
        dispatch({ type: RETURN_PAGE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        const message = error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message;
        dispatch({ type: RETURN_PAGE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
};
```

returnReducer.js

```
 export const returnPagesReducer = (state = {totalPages:[]}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case RETURN_PAGE_REQUEST:
        return { ...state, loading: true };
      case RETURN_PAGE_SUCCESS:
        return { ...state, loading: false, totalPages: action.payload,};
      case RETURN_PAGE_FAIL:
        return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

I also have a store.js and returnConstants.js that is not shown

Backend

returnRouter.js

```
returnRouter.get(
    '/num',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        const perPage = 20
        const total = await Return.countDocuments();
         console.log(total)
        const totalPages = Math.ceil(total / perPage).toString();
        console.log(totalPages)
        res.status(200).send(totalPages);
    }),
);
```

Note: `console.log(total)` and `console.log(totalPages)` are not returning anything

Comment: The error seems specific to backend. Something that the mongo query would throw. Can you try using `Return.countDocuments({})` with an empty document to see if the the total is returned?

Comment: @AnkitGupta HI, so I tried ```const total = await Return.countDocuments({}); console.log(total)``` and that's not returning anything and I am still getting the same error.  Also, I've added ```const total = await Return.countDocuments();``` to another api call that I have on my ReturnListScreen and it does work and show the count, so that aspect seems to not be the issue